# Can I do Sentiment Analysis (POS Tagging etc) on Android?

Tags: android, nlp

I am working on an `Android` Application. I want to do sentiment analysis on client side. I tried to do it using `StanfordCoreNLP` but it does not work in Android but working fine in `Java` . Is there any method to do it? Will `NDK` work? Or some other guidelines? Any help will be appreciative. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can call the web API instead of local SDK, such as [Microsoft cognitive](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api).